# How can I have a 128-bit integer in protothread in cooja simulator?

Tags: c, cooja, 128-bit

Is there any library already available in c or should I need to use an external library that will work for the cooja simulator? I have tried the GMP library for Z mote. But that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have implemented 128-bit integer manually using structure. But now I am getting memory overflow. Is there any solution to increase memory?

Comment: `I have implemented 128-bit integer manually using structure. But now I am getting memory overflow` show your solution, input and output

Comment: `I have tried the GMP library for Z mote. But that doesn't work for me` create a [mcve] to show how you tried it. "Doesn't work" doesn't mean anything and doesn't help anyone answering the question