# How to generate a random float values in cooja (c code) if I don't have time.h library to perform srand

Tags: c, cooja

```
float random_value(int min, int max)
{
        float temp = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
        return min + temp *(max - min);
}
```

I have this function, but it is not working in cooja, as it always output the same numbers over and over again, and I don't have the time.h library to make `srand()`. So, how should I print different random float values in cooja?
I should write a c function `float random_value (float min, float max)`  that could be used to implement virtual temperature sensor that could be configured to generate values between min and max value.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012155/how-to-have-a-random-number-which-changes-with-time-in-cooja-simulator-in-c-lang  it looks like it is exactly what you are asking.  And this: https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/39171545.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to `time.h` to seed the pseudo-random number generator, another way to use the current `pid` of the currently-running process.

In fact, unique filenames are sometimes generated this way:

```
getpid() returns the process ID (PID) of the calling process.
(This is often used by routines that generate unique temporary
filenames.)
```

Here's a small example that prints the current `pid` and uses it as an argument to `srand()`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int pid;
   pid = getpid();
   printf("Current process pid = %d\n", pid);
   srand((unsigned int)pid);
   printf("Random number: %d\n", rand()%100);
   return 0;
}
```

Running it once:

```
Current process pid = 197
Random number: 8
```

Running it again:

```
Current process pid = 5612
Random number: 76
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run on Linux, read [random(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/random.7.html). you could seed your PRNG by using the [getrandom(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) system call or by opening the `/dev/random` device (see [random(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html))